# List<DateTime> Post call issue

Tags: entity-framework, blazor

I'm trying to do a JSON post call using a List property (RecurrenceException) but once the AddAppointment() method is called, RecurrenceException will always be null as its supposed to be but I get this exception on my API controller:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The parameterized query '(@PK int,@Title nvarchar(8),@Description nvarchar(8),@StartDate ' expects the parameter '@RecurrenceException', which was not supplied.'

Below is my client Razor Page code:

```
 async Task AddAppointment(SchedulerCreateEventArgs e)
{
    UvwHolidayPlanner holidayPlannerItem = e.Item as UvwHolidayPlanner;

    List<DateTime> lst = new List<DateTime>();

    holidayPlanner.Pk = holidayPlannerItem.Pk;
    holidayPlanner.Title = holidayPlannerItem.Title;
    holidayPlanner.Description = holidayPlannerItem.Description;
    holidayPlanner.StartDate = holidayPlannerItem.StartDate;
    holidayPlanner.EndDate = holidayPlannerItem.EndDate;
    holidayPlanner.IsAllDay = holidayPlannerItem.IsAllDay;

    if (holidayPlannerItem.RecurrenceRule == null)
    {
        holidayPlanner.RecurrenceRule = " ";
    }
    else
    {
        holidayPlanner.RecurrenceRule = holidayPlannerItem.RecurrenceRule;
    }


    holidayPlanner.RecurrenceException = holidayPlannerItem.RecurrenceException;


    holidayPlanner.RecurrenceId = holidayPlannerItem.RecurrenceId;


    await http.CreateClient("ClientSettings").PostAsJsonAsync<UvwHolidayPlanner>($"{_URL}/api/HolidayPlannerOperations/HolidayPlanner", holidayPlanner);

    HolidayPlanners = (await http.CreateClient("ClientSettings").GetFromJsonAsync<List<UvwHolidayPlanner>>($"{_URL}/api/lookup/HolidayPlanner"))
    .OrderBy(t => t.Title)
    .ToList();

    StateHasChanged();
}
```

Below is my class code:

```
public class UvwHolidayPlanner
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsAllDay { get; set; }
    public int Pk { get; set; }
    public string RecurrenceRule { get; set; }
    public List<DateTime> RecurrenceException { get; set; }
    public int RecurrenceId { get; set; }

}
```

And below is my API controller code:

```
     [HttpPost]
    [Route("HolidayPlanner")]
    public void Post([FromBody] UvwHolidayPlanner item)
    {
        string SQLSTE = "EXEC [dbo].[usp_AddHolidayPlanner] @PK, @Title, @Description, @StartDate, @EndDate, @IsAllDay, @RecurrenceRule, @RecurrenceException, @RecurrenceId";
        using (var context = new TestAppContext())
        {
            List<SqlParameter> param = new List<SqlParameter>
            {

                new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@PK", Value = item.Pk },
                new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@Title", Value = item.Title },
                new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@Description", Value = item.Description },
                new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@StartDate", Value = item.StartDate },
                new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@EndDate", Value = item.EndDate },
                new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@IsAllDay", Value = item.IsAllDay },
                new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@RecurrenceRule", Value = item.RecurrenceRule },
                new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@RecurrenceException", Value = item.RecurrenceException },
                new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@RecurrenceId", Value = item.RecurrenceId }

            };

            context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(SQLSTE, param);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try posting an empty list not null.

Comment: @BrianParker I tried: holidayPlanner.RecurrenceException = lst; but it doesn't even call the API when I do that - when wrapped in a If(holidayPlannerItem.RecurrenceException == null). I have breakpoints on the post & its never hit

Comment: Looks like an error in usp_AddHolidayPlanner, or a NULL problem.

Comment: Your route parameter...

Comment: @HH could this be because on my table on sql the datatype is nvarchar(50) & not a List<Datetime>?. I understand thats not a data type in SQL

Comment: @BrianParker It worked perfect until I added RecurrenceException to it

Comment: This is an SQL question but you didn't post any of the SQL. Yes, thar List<> will need a conversion but that does not explain this error message.

Comment: The error means you didn't have `@RecurrenceException` into the sql.Try to check  the value of it.